# softether Layer3 routing between virtual hubs

Tags: softether

straightforward scenario but I've spent hours on this without success
I have one server with 2 virtual hubs configured with secureNAT enabled and DHCP set with the below

```
virtual hub1
192.168.30.1 - 192.168.50.200

virtual hub2
192.168.100.30 - 192.168.100.200
```

I want to route between the 2 hubs using the Layer3 switch that I have configured with the below settings for the virtual interface

```
192.168.1.50.201 / 255.255.0.0 
192.168.100.201 / 255.255.0.0
```

the L3 switch is started and online

From virtual hub1 I can ping 192.168.50.201 all fine
from virtual hub 2 I cannot ping 192.168.100.201 ???

I can see the interfaces created in the IP tables section on both hubs - see attachments
End goal is cross communication between hubs.

please any advice appreciated - this really seems quite forward without success

[image]

[image]

Comment: AShah i agree with jokinenand you may want to use the static route push on each virtual hub
that could help you either and don'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have mask `255.255.0.0` i.e. `192.168.30.1/16` it covers range from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255`. Therefore, it's looking for `192.168.100.201` on the same subnet i.e. using only layer 2 without any routing.

For routing, you need to use subnets that won't overlap. If you wish to continue using these ranges, that would be:

- `192.168.0.0/18` from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.63.255` (mask `255.255.192.0` with 16384 hosts)
- `192.168.100.0/24` from `192.168.100.0` to `192.168.100.255` (mask `255.255.255.0` with 256 hosts)

After learning the basics on IPv4 subnetting you'd choose better IP ranges according to your needs for the amount of hosts on the same subnet.